Foucault's own explanation of his pendulum
Foucault never gave a detailed explanation of why the period of the turning of his pendulum depended on the sine of the latitude, but he wrote a letter saying as follows:

"I begin by boldly adopting as a postulate the following. When the vertical, always of course lying in the plane of oscillation, changes its direction in space, the successive positions of the plane of oscillation are determined by the condition that the angles between successive positions shall be minimized. To state this in ordinary language, when the vertical direction changes from its initial position, the plane of oscillation follows, while remaining as parallel as possible to the initial plane of oscillation."

(I've taken this translation of the original French from a book review by Robert H. Romer in American Journal of Physics 72, 286 (2004))
Could anyone explain how to derive the sine factor from Foucault's postulate?
I've seen a brief derivation on page 152 of William Tobin's "The Life and Science of Léon Foucault, but it is too short and I don't get it.

Foucault in his paper wrote - In order to determine the law according to which this motion varies in the various latitudes, it is necessary to have recourse either to analysis, or to mechanical and geometrical considerations, which are not included in the limited scope of this note; I must, therefore, confine myself to stating that the two methods agree, by neglecting certain secondary phenomena, to show the angular displacement of the plane of oscillation as de- .It must be equal to the angular motion of the earth in the same time multiplied by the sine of latitude. (Microsoft translate)

I have expanded my answer. I discuss in what way Foucault's proposal does not count as an explanation, and I describe how to recognize that the slower veering of the plane of swing at non-polar latitude is a dynamical phenomenon

I'm not sure if this would answers your question, but here's an intuitive explanation of why this proportionality factor has been added, as you seem to be asking.
Let's recall that the Foucault pendulum a simple pendulum designed as an experiment to demonstrate the Earth's rotation. The pendulum is long and heavy enough to ensure that its plane of oscillation can be seen to rotate throughout the day. The ordinary pendulum model neglects these aspects.
However, the Earth rotates on itself (it also rotates in space around other bodies, but we are neglecting this aspect here). At the poles, the pendulum swings in a fixed plane, so the plane of the pendulum appears to rotate through 360° as the Earth completes one full rotation, but this is not true at other points on the planet where the point of attachment of the pendulum cannot be considered a fixed point since it too is moving as the Earth rotates.
The plane in which the pendulum swings is also in motion. This is why the time taken for the pendulum to complete a full rotation (relative to its location on earth) must be corrected by astronomical considerations depending on where the pendulum is swinging, typically by taking a time proportional to the sidereal day. The constant of proportionality is the inverse of the sine of the latitude of the location. But why?
We forgot to discuss one aspect of this explanation: the Coriolis force. When a body moves in the Earth's rotating frame of reference, the Coriolis force acts perpendicularly to the direction of motion and always makes a certain angle $\varphi$ with the local vertical direction ($\varphi$ is the latitude!) The result is that the "Coriolis frequency" $f$ is (where $\Omega$ is the rotation rate of the Earth)
$$
f=2\Omega\sin\varphi.
$$
I will let you to consult the wikipedia page on the subject. Foucault adds a correction to the sidereal day by setting the proportionality factor equal to $2\Omega/f=1/\sin\varphi$ so as to have a dimensionless constant taking into account the Coriolis effect in relation to the earth's rotation.
Rigorous justifications are done mathematically, but that's a more intuitive explanation that I hope is somewhat enlightening.

Thank you for the answer, Foxy, but I'm afraid that my question is not about how to derive the sine factor in general but about how to derive the sine factor from Foucault's postulate, that is I'm trying to understand Foucault's own explanation.


the plane of oscillation follows, while remaining as parallel as
possible to the initial plane of oscillation

Suppose the plane of oscillation initially aligned with the South-North direction as shown in the picture. If we are in the Northern hemisphere at some latitude $\theta$, the effect of the rotation of the Earth can be thought as gently continuously moving all the pendulum to East in a hypothetical stationary Earth.
A small shift L, corresponding to a change $\delta \phi$ of latitude is $L = Rcos(\theta)\delta\phi$, where R is the radius of the Earth.
The plane of oscillation has no reason to keep South-North after the shift. It remains parallel as shown in the picture, and making now an angle $\delta \alpha$ with the local South-North direction.
But not exactly parallel, because it is of course vertical at both locations. That is the meaning of 'as parallel as possible' of the citation, as I understand.
The length of the same shift at another latitude a little bit North of the first one is: $$L = Rcos(\theta + \delta \theta)\delta\phi + \delta L = R(cos(\theta)cos(\delta \theta) - sin(\theta)sin(\delta \theta))\delta\phi + \delta L$$
Noting that $Rcos(\theta)\delta\phi = L$, and that for small $\delta\theta$, $cos(\delta\theta) \approx 1$ and $sin(\delta\theta) \approx \delta\theta$:
$$\delta L = R\delta \theta sin(\theta)\delta\phi$$
Now, dividing by the change of latitude:
$$\frac{\delta L}{R\delta \theta} = sin(\theta)\delta\phi$$
For small angles, the tangent is equal to the angle. So, the left side of the equation is the angle $\delta \alpha$. Letting the $\delta$'s tend to zero, we get the differential equation:
$$\frac{d\alpha}{d\phi} = sin(\theta)$$


The book by William Tobin that you mention is in my opinion the best source for Foucault's thoughts about the veering of the pendulum.
Foucault had extraordinary capability in experimental physics. My understanding was that in his time he was the leading man in the manufacturing of mirrors for telescopes.
As to the pendulum:
If memory serves me: William Tobin describes in his book that Foucault had mentioned to friends (or to one friend) his personal views on how to explain the veering. These friends (or this one friend) had advised Foucault to not put those views to paper, certainly not in the main papers about the pendulum, on which his reputation would rest.
That is to say: based on the available evidence Tobin had come to the conclusion that Foucault did not have a physical understanding of the veering of the plane of swing of the pendulum.

I think among the scientists of the time (1851) Charles Wheatstone was the only one who understood the veering of the plane of swing.
Wikisource:
Note relating to M. Foucault's new mechanical proof of the Rotation of the Earth

(In an article about the Foucault pendulum on my website I discuss  Wheatstone's insight. A link to my website is available on my stackexchange profile page.)


[Later edit]
To prepare for what I want to convey I point out the difference between Kepler's laws of celestial motion on one hand, and the laws of motion and the inverse square law of gravity on the other hand.
The recognition of the inverse square law of gravity moved the description of physics taking place to a deeper level.
Kepler's laws of celestial motion exist at the level of direct observation data. Kepler's laws hint at the existence of a deeper law, but the form of that deeper law is far from obvious.
The nature of Foucault's proposal is comparable to Kepler's laws.
Also: the proposal of "as parallel as possible" is ambiguous. It may be that what Foucault had in mind was to project the amplitude of the plane of swing onto the plane of the Equator, with the supposition that the veering of the plane of swing is slower in proportion to the size of that projection.

The thing is:
The veering of the plane of swing is a dynamical phenomenon. This can be seen as follows: at the latitude of Paris a full precession cycle takes about 32 hours. Therefore: after 24 hours the pendulum has completed 3/4th of a complete cycle.
Let the pendulum be started in north-south direction. After 24 hours the Earth is back in the same orientation as 24 hours before, and by that time the pendulum is swinging in east-west direction.
That is: the direction of the momentum of the pendulum bob has changed from north-south to east-west. The pendulum bob has exchanged momentum with the Earth. It is due to that exchange of momentum that a Foucault pendulum at non-polar latitude veers slower (relative to the Earth) than at the poles
That is proof that the (slower) veering of the plane of swing is a dynamical phenomenon. It's an exchange of momentum phenomenon. That means that kinematic explanation is out.
Let me be blunt about it: any kinematic explanation that produces the sine-of-the-latitude relation is a fluke.
The assumptions of the attempted kinematic explanation may fortuitously line up to produce the sine-of-the-latitude relation, but there is no substance to it.
